# Django file upload using Form

Tags: python, django, file, upload

I'm trying to upload a file on a model in Django framework.

```py
class banner(models.Model):
    #id is made by Django
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    register_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

this is the model:

```py
class BannerForm(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_by=forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    company=forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    data_type=forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    register_date=forms.DateField()
    file=forms.FileField()
    file_name=forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

this is the form:

```py
def add_form(request):
    form=BannerForm()
    last=models.banner.objects.all().last()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.BannerForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data['created_by']
            new_banner=models.banner()
            new_banner.id=last.id+1
            new_banner.name=form.cleaned_data['name']
            new_banner.register_date=form.cleaned_data['register_date']
            new_banner.company=form.cleaned_data['company']
            new_banner.file=form.cleaned_data['file']
            new_banner.file_name=new_banner.file.name
            new_banner.created_by=form.cleaned_data['created_by']
            new_banner.save()

    return render(request, "add_banner.html",{"form":form})
```

this is the view.

Now every time I try to add a banner, I browse the file, but after I click "submit", it is that the file must be chosen, like it doesn't recognize what I browse to the form button.

Comment: I forgot to mention: it says The submitted file is empty.

Comment: Do you have the `enctype` set in your form?

Comment: I have the enctype only in the add_banner.html template enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 3):

well you need to specify the upload path in your models

```
file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True,upload_to='files')
```

and make sure you have `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` defined in your settings.py

in your form

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn) I have those and i modify but still nothing the same thing

Comment: try the edited ans, and after adding the upload path to model, dont forget to make migrations and migrate

Comment: I was trying to upload an empty file, my dumb mistake, but question, when i try to upload the same file to a table where i have already have a row with that file it will overwritten?

Comment: if you are editing then it will overrite the old one, but the file will stay in the media folder

Comment: k, so sorry for bothering all of you with my lack of knowledge, it is the first time when i work with django. So now they store all my uploads in the main file of the project. Should i change  file=models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='files') to  file=models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='files/Media') if i wan the files to be fount the folder called Media?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form definition.

```
<form method="post" action="your action" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: <form action="" method= "POST", enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                         <input type="submit" class="button", value="Insert">
                </form>

Answer (score 0):

Try this something like this :

Models.py :

```
class banner(models.Model):
#id is made by Django
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
company = models.CharField(max_length=255)
register_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/', null=True, blank=True)
file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

forms.py :

```
class BannerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = banner #Or Banner ??
        fields = ('name', 'created_by', 'company', 'file', 'file_name' )
```

views.py :

```
from myapp.forms import BannerForm

if request.method == "POST":
    form = BannerForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        entry = form.save(commit=False)
        entry.name = request.POST['name']
        entry.created_by = request.POST['created_by']
        entry.company = request.POST['company']
        entry.file_name = request.POST['file_name']
        form.save()

    else:
      form = BannerForm()

return render(request, "add_banner.html",locals())
```

And like already said, don't forget :

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.name}}
    {{form.created_by}}
    {{form.company}}
    {{form.file_name}}
    {{form.file}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You don't have to specify these things :

```
new_banner.file=form.cleaned_data['file']
```

`new_banner.register_date=form.cleaned_data['register_date']` -> useless because in your model you set auto_now_add=True, so you don't need te make a field in your HTML form.

Note : if your field `created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)` is to put an existing user, so you should make a foreign key field like :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Created by")
```

Comment: k, so sorry for bothering all of you with my lack of knowledge, it is the first time when i work with django. So now they store all my uploads in the main file of the project. Should i change file=models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='files') to file=models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='files/Media') if i wan the files to be fount the folder called Media?

Comment: You can try. Django will automatically create a folder if it doesn't exists.

Comment: For example you can try also :  upload_to='media/banner/whatever/'')

Comment: And the media folder will be created in the Project folder?

Comment: I think yes. On the root of your project folder, you will find a new folder called media or whatever you called it.